# how to pass dropdownlist selected value to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

binding of dropdownlist is as follows

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.vDeptCode, (SelectList)ViewBag.deptList, "- Select Department -", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddl_Dept" })
```

On the same view i Have add button also after clicking on add button i have to pass deptCode value to my Action for that i have done

```
function CreateNewVoucher() 
{
    window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Add", "Voucher", new { @vDeptCode =@Html.Raw(Model.vDeptCode) })";
}
```

but it always pass null value.
Please guide me how to pass value to my ActionResult in Controller

Comment: `@Url.Action()` is razor code which is evaluated on the server before its sent to the view. The route value is not updated just because you change a value in your dropdown. You need to build the url based on the selected value using javascript/jquery

Answer (score 0):

Look, How i am passing the `DropdownList` selected value to Controller Post Method.

I have add only necessary Codes here, Please follow this to get your Dropdown value.

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    AccountModel account = new AccountModel();
    account.accountStatusList= ObjContext.Status.ToList();
    return View(account);
}
```

**Custom Model Class**

```
public class AccountModel
{
    public int selectedStatusId { get; set; }
    public List<Status> accountStatusList { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model Nop.Models.AccountModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
     <div class="row-fluid span12">
          <div class="span3">
             <p><strong>Account Status :</strong></p>
           </div>
           <div class="span5">
             // Bind the dropdown by List.
             @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedStatusId, new SelectList(Model.accountStatusList, "StatusId", "StatusName"), "--Select--")
           </div>
     </div>
    <div class="row-fluid span12">
          <button class="btn btn-inverse" type="submit" title="Search for Account"><span class="fa fa-search"> Search</span></button>              
    </div>
}
```

**Controller Post Method**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(AccountModel account)
{
    int selectedID = account.selectedStatusId; // You can find your selectedID here..      
    return View(account);
}
```

See [ViewBag vs Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625858/c-sharp-mvc-model-vs-viewbag?rq=1).